# When executing Python via xp_cmdshell, print does not return to the SQL Output

Tags: python, sql-server, xp-cmdshell

When executing the following in SQL Server 2019, the output returned is NULL:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell '<location>\python.exe <location>\HelloWorld.py'
```

When executing HelloWorld.py in Command Prompt or PowerShell, Hello World! is returned. The HelloWorld.py file contains print("Hello World!").

I tried wrapping the python command in a .bat file:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell '<location>\HelloWorld.bat'
```

The output returned was the following:

```
NULL
<location>\python.exe <location>\HelloWorld.py
NULL
```

The expected output, according to this [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-approaches-to-execute-python-in-sql-server/):

```
NULL
<location>\python.exe <location>\HelloWorld.py
Hello World!
NULL
```

How do I get the expected output?

Comment: What is the `<location>` supposed to be?  What you want is `EXEC xp_cmdshell { 'python.exe HelloWorld.py' }`, assuming Python is on the path.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` can be difficult to use and have security implications. Have you considered using `sp_execute_external_script` to run Python scripts, which is built to allow you to pass parameters and resultsets back and forth?

Comment: Given that .bat files have all kinds of redirect capabilities - able to send stdout and stderr to your choice of files, devices and NUL: - what's in the .bat file?

Comment: the <location> is just my location on PC. I tried to just use py HelloWorld.py, but it struggled to find the python command. I do have python in PATH, so I can execute python in command prompt or powershell without issues. The .bat file contains only <location>\python.exe <location>\HelloWorld.py. I know xp_cmdshell has security implications but at the moment I'm just tinkering locally. I will probably execute python via task scheduler when I move my project to production, but I'd like to understand why this doesn't work out of curiosity!

Comment: Probably because the user that the SQL Server service is running under does not have permissions in that location.

Comment: what permission would I need to add in which location? The service user has read/write in the location of the HelloWorld.py file.